# Three-dimensional light bulbs

Tags: visual, grid-deduction, three-dimensional

> This is a three-dimensional **Akari** puzzle (also known as **Light Up**). The six squares represent the layers of a $6\times6\times6$ cube, top to bottom. The objective is to add light bulbs into any number of cells so that the resulting grid satifies the following rules:<sup>1</sup>
>
> - Black cells are walls and cannot contain light bulbs.
> - Numbers in black cells indicate how many light bulbs are directly adjacent to that cell (vertically, horizontally or along the Z-axis).
> - A light bulb illuminates its own cell as well as every cell visible from it in all six directions (up/down, right/left, and both ways along the Z-axis), continuing until a wall comes in the way.
> - Every white square must be illuminated by at least one light bulb.
> - No light bulb may be illuminated by another light bulb.
>
> **Note**: The solution is unique and solvable by logic alone. No guesswork or trial-and-error is necessary here.
>
> [image]
>
> <sub><sup>1</sup> Paraphrased from the original rules on [Nikoli](http://www.nikoli.co.jp/en/puzzles/akari.html)</sub>

Comment: left top corner is top, right top corner 3rd layer, right? +1!

Comment: @OmegaKrypton That's correct, although in this case I think it doesn't matter.

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Hmm, correction: Actually the order does indeed matter (even though top vs bottom doesn't). Sorry about that. Better add in the layer numbers.

Comment: Your rules do not say what the numbers are for.

Comment: @LeppyR64 Wow, how'd I miss that? Missing rule added. Thanks!

Comment: Very well crafted!  The difficulty was spot-on, in my opinion.  I wouldn't say "no" to more of these.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Like that?

> Red = light bulb, yellow = light      [image: Solution]
>  [Start from bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3VfM.png)
>  1 because you can't place light bulb above (in z) "2" and next to "1" can be only one, so it has to be there.
>  2 because you can't place light bulb above (in z) "2" and there is already light from first light bulb
>  3 since second light bulb eliminates one solution
>  4 because 1st and 3rd light bulbs eliminates rest
>  5 because of 4th and so on…

Comment: Wow, that was fast. Everything's correct.

Comment: The answer would be even better, if the logical deduction for the solution would be present.

Comment: @BmyGuest oh come on, it is too easy :P But added first few moves. Solution took me something under 20 mins, I would be happy for harder.

Comment: Didn't realize it turned out that easy. My intention was to leave a "unique" starting point, but turns out there was another way to start which you found. (The idea was to begin with row 1 col 1 on #6.) Let's see if I can come up with a "hard mode" follow-up...

Comment: See? Giving your description helped jafe... I think in the spirit of the site, it's always a good idea to describe the answer better. +1 from me now.

Comment: Even if I spotted this right when it posted I wouldn't have beaten your time.  Well done!  Knowing what I know now I wouldn't have bothered trying to add so many X's everywhere like I do in 2D.